# How to create a structure of html tags on php

Tags: php, dom, replace

I have to create a this html structure:

```
<figure class="op-interactive">
    <iframe>
        <div>
            <script async="" height="" src="src" width=""></script>
        </div>
    </iframe>
</figure>
```

and this is my code:

```
$media_embed = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($media_embed as $media){
    $scriptstag = $media->getElementsByTagName('script');                           
    foreach ($scriptstag as $scripts) {
        $src= $scripts->getAttribute('src');
        $newFigure = $doc->createElement('figure');
        $newFigure->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');

        $newiFrame = $doc->createElement('iframe');
        $newFigure->appendChild($newiFrame);

        $newDiv = $doc->createElement('div');
        $newiFrame->appendChild($newDiv);                                   

        $scripts->parentNode->insertBefore($newFigure, $scripts);
        $newiFrame->appendChild($scripts);
    }
}
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

But the output is this:

```
<figure class="op-interactive">
    <iframe>
        <div>
        </div>
        <script async="" height="" src="src" width=""></script>
    </iframe>
</figure>
```

i dont know how to insert `script` tag between `div` tag,
is there something missing in my code?
im using this page to share my test:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00c285949a467fe44d4a5ce2ed002e6b0ef670a6

could you please help me?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are appending your script to the `$newiFrame`

Try adding it to the div:
`$newDiv->appendChild($scripts);`

Comment: Hi, I've already tried, when I do that, the page is just loading

Comment: You are also trying to insert it before the $newFigure: `$scripts->parentNode->insertBefore($newFigure, $scripts);` is this required?

Comment: i insert before and this is the answer: Fatal error:  Uncaught DOMException: Hierarchy Request Error in 27
Stack trace:
DOMNode-insertBefore(Object(DOMElement), Object(DOMElement)),

Comment: i need $scripts->parentNode->insertBefore($newFigure, $scripts); without that i dont get nothing

Comment: im using this page to share my test:http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00c285949a467fe44d4a5ce2ed002e6b0ef670a6

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
$body1='<div class="media_embed"><script async="" height="" src="src"></script></div>';
$htmlEncoded = mb_convert_encoding($body1, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$opcionesLibXML = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD;
@$doc->loadHTML($htmlEncoded, $opcionesLibXML);
$media_embed = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($media_embed as $media){
    $scriptstag = $media->getElementsByTagName('script');
    foreach ($scriptstag as $scripts) {
        $iframe = $doc->createElement('iframe');
        $div = $doc->createElement('div');
        $newScript = $doc->createElement('newscript');
        $newScript->setAttribute('src', $scripts->getAttribute('src'));
        $figure = $doc->createElement('figure');
        $figure->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
        $figure->appendChild($iframe);
        $iframe->appendChild($div);
        $div->appendChild($newScript);
        $scripts->parentNode->replaceChild($figure, $scripts);

    }
}
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
$body1 = str_replace('<newscript', '<script', $body1);
$body1 = str_replace('</newscript>', '</script>', $body1);
echo $body1;
```

but i dont know why if y use:

```
$newScript = $doc->createElement('newscript');
```

i  get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded
```

that why i use `newscript` and then i replace that tags

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0c42f2b9823bf41e92267af89b770848682215a